# Tkinter event_generate freezes thread join

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, events, deadlock

I have a tkinter application which is running CPU intensive tasks. Therefore, to keep the GUI responsive, I put the tasks in their own threads and communicate to the GUI via events. This works well and to my knowledge should be safe as long as I don't manipulate the tkinter widgets and vars directly from the worker threads.
In fact, it's working.
But when I need to stop a worker task, I command the worker thread to stop with a *threading.Event* called *must_stop* and call join on it from the GUI. However, the join freezes when the worker thread generates one more event before realizing it has to stop. This is quite annoying.

I found some ways to avoid the freeze making the code somewhat ugly. I can:

1. use a loop checking *thread.is_alive()* while calling *update()* on the tkinter window. Not sure if this could spoil my mainloop
2. check before every *event_generate* call if *must_stop* has been set (or maybe better using a *threading.Lock* or *threading.Condition* applied by the GUI before join is called)

I have put a short working example below.
Btw: it does not make a difference if I use *event_generate* to procude an event or e.g. a *tk.IntVar* for the GUI (either tracing the var or setting the *textvariable* of the label - even when it's not connected at all, it will cause a deadlock during join)

Is there a more elegant way letting me call *thread.join()* without deadlock? Or a better concept for communication with a tkinter GUI? To my knowledge tkinter events are said to be "thread-safe".

```
import threading
import tkinter as tk
import time

must_stop = threading.Event()
counter_lock = threading.Lock()
counter = 0

def run_thread(root):
    #Threaded procedure counting seconds and generating events for the root window whenever
    #the variable changes
    global counter
    while not must_stop.is_set():
        time.sleep(1)
        with counter_lock:
            counter += 1
        root.event_generate('<<Counter>>', when = 'tail')

class CounterWindow(tk.Tk):
    #Window class for the counter
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.label = tk.Label(self, text = 'Hello!')
        self.label.pack()
        self.button = tk.Button(text = 'Start counter', command = self.start_thread)
        self.button.pack()
        self.bind('<<Counter>>', self.update_counter)
        
    def update_counter(self, event):
        #Writes counter to label, triggered by <<Counter>> event
        with counter_lock:
            self.label.configure(text = counter)   # replacing this line
            #print(counter)                                 # with a tk-free routine does not prevent deadlock
            
    def start_thread(self):
        #Button command to start the thread
        self.thread = threading.Thread(target = run_thread, args = (self, ))
        self.thread.start()
        self.button.configure(text = 'Stop counter', command = self.stop_thread)
        
    def stop_thread(self):
        #Button command to stop the thread. Attention: Causing deadlock !!!
        #self.unbind('<<Counter>>')    # does not prevent deadlock either
        must_stop.set()
        self.thread.join()                                    # replacing this line
        #while self.thread.is_alive():                  # with this loop prevents deadlock
        #    self.update()
        self.button.configure(text = 'Exit counter', command = self.destroy)
        
#Start the app
window = CounterWindow()
window.mainloop()
```

Using python version 3.9.5. Tested on Windows and linux

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't give me any error and runs fine:

```py
import threading
import tkinter as tk
import time

must_stop = threading.Event()
counter_lock = threading.Lock()
counter = 0

def run_thread(root):
    global counter
    while not must_stop.is_set():
        time.sleep(1)
        with counter_lock:
            counter += 1
        if must_stop.is_set():
            return None
        root.event_generate('<<Counter>>', when="tail")


class CounterWindow(tk.Tk):
    # Window class for the counter
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.label = tk.Label(self, text="Hello!")
        self.label.pack()
        self.button = tk.Button(text="Start counter", command=self.start_thread)
        self.button.pack()
        self.bind("<<Counter>>", self.update_counter)
        
    def update_counter(self, event):
        #Writes counter to label, triggered by <<Counter>> event
        with counter_lock:
            self.label.configure(text=counter)
            
    def start_thread(self):
        #Button command to start the thread
        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=run_thread, args=(self, ))
        self.thread.start()
        self.button.configure(text="Stop counter", command=self.stop_thread)
        
    def stop_thread(self):
        must_stop.set()
        # self.thread.join() # Don't think it's nessasary
        self.button.configure(text="Exit counter", command=self.destroy)
        
# Start the app
window = CounterWindow()
window.mainloop()
```

I added another check before calling `.event_generate()` so that the event isn't generated if `must_stop` is set. Also I removed the `.join()`, I am not a `threading` expert but from what I know it's not really necessary.

The bigger problem with your code is that `tkinter` it self isn't thread-safe. Try [this](https://pastebin.com/wF5Fn19a) example. It crashes the python interpreter even though no `tkinter` method is called from the other thread. Just passing in a `tkinter` widget/variable to another thread can cause trouble in some cases.

Comment: Hi TheLizzard, thanks for your help. I think what you suggested is exactly my workaround 2 that I mentioned. It's not really safe. _must_stop.set()_ and _self.thread.join()_ could be called directly after the query upon must_stop.is_set() causing a deadlock too. However, it can be solved by using a Condition with a Lock which is verified before every event_generate(). Still, my idea is that there must be a better solution to the problem and I'm wondering if there is a standard way of adressing this Thread issue.

Comment: @rhb My bad. I forgot that you mentioned it. Also with the code as I have it, you can change the `while not must_stop.is_set()` to `while True`, if you are worried about performance.

Comment: Btw, your bug example does not scare me too much :-) because it can be solved by shutting down all threads before exiting mainloop. That's what I am doing anyway. But I need the join in my example - or waiting for not is_alive() -  because in my real app more threads will be started later on that have to make sure that the other thread has finished.

Comment: @rhb I would suggest putting the threads in a list and calling `.join()` on them after the `.mainloop()`. It should stop the issue I talked about

Comment: Your absolutely right about tkinter widgets/vars that must not be modified from the outside. My solution is to use a thread-safe queue and events to notify about updates which then modify the tk.Variables. So far this worked well for me and I don't get any complains from tkinter about "main thread not in main loop"